# Sending data on server by fetch

Tags: javascript, express

Can someone explain to me why after sending a request, server returns `POST {} {}`- I mean empty objects?

I don't know where this data is. Why did it dissapear?

[image]

I have no idea how to solve it...

index.js:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("form");

  form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
    console.log("włącza sie");

    event.preventDefault();

    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    fetch("http:localhost:3000/register", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, password })
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  });
});

//server.js:

const http = require("http");
const app = require("./app");

const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server włączony");
});

//app.js

const loginRoute = require("./api/routes/loginRoute");
const registerRoute = require("./api/routes/registerRoute");
const verify = require("./autorization/verify");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.method, req.query, req.body);
  next();
});

app.use("/", loginRoute);

app.use("/", registerRoute);

app.use(verify);
```

Comment: Please show an image of the browser address bar from the same view that creates the error you've displayed in the image above.

Comment: Your image screenshot shows a CORS error.  You are trying to do an ajax call from the browser with `fetch()` to a host/port combination that is different than what the web page was loaded from.  That is not allowed by the browser unless the target server explicitly allows it by setting CORS headers on the server.

Comment: you are fetching on `'http:localhost:3000/register'` but i don't see `/register` around. can you post content of `./api/routes/registerRoute`?

Comment: I wonder if it could be as simple as you need to make `'http:localhost:3000/register`' into a proper URL `'http://localhost:3000/register'` when you call `fetch()`.

Comment: @Theo - great catch. Didn't even see that.

Comment: You must ensure your address bar does not look like this: `file:///...` when you view the file with the register.js it. You must request the page from the server: `http://localhost:3000/...`

Comment: So should I create another server to this page? Why it won't work with flile:/// ?

Answer (score 0):

based from your screenshot, there's a `CORS` issue. You can overcome that using 
https://github.com/expressjs/cors middleware

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

or enable CORS for the specific route only

```
app.use('/', cors(), registerRoute);
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. It appears the HTML file was loaded from the file browser rather then the server. That's why I requested an image of the browsers address bar.

Comment: yeah that's also possible. only way to confirm is let @desperate let us know where he loads it or show us  address bar

Comment: Well we do have a very strong clue. Look closely at the image. When ever the CORS error show "Origin "null" is not allow access..." _usually_ means `file:` vs. `http:`

Comment: good point. also, he's trying to access `localhost` so it should work unless he implicitly blacklist `localhost` & return CORS error

Comment: With cors it doesn't throw the error. But still this object are empty

Comment: {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/register", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: "cors"url: "http://localhost:3000/register"__proto__: Response

Comment: ok so `CORS` issue is now resolved. Now you need to show us the content of `./api/routes/registerRoute` so we can debug further

Comment: Ok I will show you this file when I come back home, but line which show me req.method, req.body, req.query in console is over this one with registerRoute. It should be execute before registerRoute. Am I wrong? So why this console.log show post {} {}

Comment: you need to show us the `./app.js` and `./api.routes/registerRoute` so we can be specific. but i strongly suspect you don't parse the request yet. you can use this middleware to do it https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Answer (score 0):

registerRoute:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const register = require('../../mongo/register');

router.post('/register',register);


module.exports = router;
```

register.js:

```
const mongo = require('./database');
const User = require('../api/patterns/user');


const register = (req,res)=>{

 const toSave = new User(req.body); 


 User.findOne({name: req.body.name},(err,name)=>{

  if(err) throw err;

  if(!name){


        toSave.save( (err)=> {

             if (err) throw err;
              console.log('user zapisany');

             });

   }else{
    console.log('juz taki istnieje');

  }

  });
};
```

app.js:

```
const loginRoute = require('./api/routes/loginRoute');
const registerRoute = require('./api/routes/registerRoute');
const verify = require('./autorization/verify');


var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', (req,res,next)=>{console.log(req.method, req.query, req.body); 
next();});

app.use('/', loginRoute);

app.use('/', registerRoute);

app.use(verify);






module.exports = app;
```

It still returns  empty objects :(